ADB Uninstall failed - Delete_failed_internal_error
I recently buy a new phone and I want to reinstall an app but I've the message "the application was not installed because the package conflicts with a package already present"
I can list all packages by typing ./adb shell cmd package list packages -u
So I try to uninstall it from adb with dev options and debogage USB by typing  ./adb uninstall package:com.snapchat.android but I've the message Failure [DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR]
I try to understand how it works but I'm a little stuck here
Thanks for your help :)

That package may be installed in the system-partition - or maybe as another user. If you cannot uninstall SnapChat via the GUI, you're likely not going to uninstalled it with adb either. And when using root to uninstall it, this will prevent future OTA updates.

Besides "how to uninstall SnapChat" doesn't exactly qualify as "programming related". There's another site on the SE netowrk, where such questions would rather be accepted: https://android.stackexchange.com
